# Python for the Absolute Beginner roadblock; Chapter 5, Challenge #2 - invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, syntax-error

I'm new to programming; I only began seriously studying it about a month ago.

The book I've been reading is Python for the Absolute Beginner, and I've hit a snag on chapter 5's challenge section. I've been working my way through this book at a steady pace, and have previously only failed one challenge. This new one is giving me an "invalid syntax" error and I don't know why.

To my (admittedly inexperienced) mind everything seems to be in order; *I cannot fathom what I did wrong.*

Here is the code:

```
 #Character Creator

#Establish defualt stats
ws = 10
st = 10
dx = 10
ht = 10
points = 30

#Tell the user about the program
print(
    """
Welcome to the character creator. Here you will allocate a pool of 30
points between 4 different stats: Strength, Dexterity, Health, and Wisdom.
You may also decrease any of these stats to gain extra points.
The game is over when your point pool is empty.
    """)

#Set the selection process to continue until the user has spent their points
while points > 0:
    #Tell the user what their starting stats are and how to select them
    print("\nHere are your current stats: ")
    print("1 - Strength: ", st)
    print("2 - Dexterity: ", dx)
    print("3 - Health: ", ht)
    print("4 - Wisdom : ", ws)
    print("Remaining points: ", points)

    #Let the player choose a stat to interact with
    chosen_stat = input("\nSelect a stat: ")
    #What to do if the player chooses Strength
    if chosen_stat == "1":
        print("\nYou have selected Strength.")
        print("Press 1 to increase it")
        print("Press 2 to decrease it")
        #Establish if the stat is being increased or decreased
        up_or_down_st = input("")
        #If the stat is being increased
        if up_or_down_st == "1":
            spent_points = int(input("How many points will you spend?: ")
            #Ensure that the player cannot spend more points than they have; 'while' this is where the error is
            while spent_points > points:
                               print("You don't have that many points.")
                               spent_points = int(input("Try a lower number: ")

            #Allocate the points and inform the user
            st += spent_points
            points -= spent_points
            print("Your have spent ", spent_points, " and increased your Strength to ", st)

        #The process is almost identical for decreasing stats
        if up_or_down_st == "2":
            gained_points = int(input("How many points will you deduct?: ")
            while gained_points > st:
                               print("You don't have that many points.")
                               spent_points = int(input("Try a lower number: ")

            st -= gained_points
            points += gained_points
            print("Your have gained ", gained_points, " points and decreased your Strength to ", st)

     #The process is the same for all the different stats
     if chosen_stat == "2":
        print("\nYou have selected Dexterity.")
        print("Press 1 to increase it")
        print("Press 2 to decrease it")
        up_or_down_dx = input("")
        if up_or_down_dx == "1":
            spent_points = int(input("How many points will you spend?: ")
            while spent_points > points:
                               print("You don't have that many points.")
                               spent_points = int(input("Try a lower number: ")

            dx += spent_points
            points -= spent_points
            print("Your have spent ", spent_points, " and increased your Strength to ", dx)

        if up_or_down_dx == "2":
            gained_points = int(input("How many points will you deduct?: ")
            while gained_points > dx:
                               print("You don't have that many points.")
                               spent_points = int(input("Try a lower number: ")

            dx -= gained_points
            points += gained_points
            print("Your have gained ", gained_points, " points and decreased your Dexterity to ", dx)

     if chosen_stat == "3":
        print("\nYou have selected Health.")
        print("Press 1 to increase it")
        print("Press 2 to decrease it")
        up_or_down_ht = input("")
        if up_or_down_ht == "1":
            spent_points = int(input("How many points will you spend?: ")
            while spent_points > points:
                               print("You don't have that many points.")
                               spent_points = int(input("Try a lower number: ")

            ht += spent_points
            points -= spent_points
            print("Your have spent ", spent_points, " and increased your Health to ", ht)

        if up_or_down_ht == "2":
            gained_points = int(input("How many points will you deduct?: ")
            while gained_points > ht:
                               print("You don't have that many points.")
                               spent_points = int(input("Try a lower number: ")

            ht -= gained_points
            points += gained_points
            print("Your have gained ", gained_points, " points and decreased your Health to ", ht)

     if chosen_stat == "4":
        print("\nYou have selected Wisdom.")
        print("Press 1 to increase it")
        print("Press 2 to decrease it")
        up_or_down_ws = input("")
        if up_or_down_ws == "1":
            spent_points = int(input("How many points will you spend?: ")
            while spent_points > points:
                               print("You don't have that many points.")
                               spent_points = int(input("Try a lower number: ")

            ws += spent_points
            points -= spent_points
            print("Your have spent ", spent_points, " and increased your Wisdom to ", ws)

        if up_or_down_ws == "2":
            gained_points = int(input("How many points will you deduct?: ")
            while gained_points > ws:
                               print("You don't have that many points.")
                               spent_points = int(input("Try a lower number: ")

            ws -= gained_points
            points += gained_points
            print("Your have gained ", gained_points, " points and decreased your Wisdom to ", ws)

#Show the final character when all the points are gone
print("You have spent all your points.")
print("Here is your completed character:")
print("Your Strength is: ", st)
print("Your Dexterity is: ", dx)
print("Your Health is: ", ht)
print("Your Wisdom is: ", ws)

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit")
```

I know it's probably very inelegant, but this was the best I could do with my limited experience. The error occurs on this line:

```
while spent_points > points:
```

The error says "invalid syntax". I don't know what that means or what I've done wrong. The highlighted text for the error was just the "while" part. I tried changing the "while" to "if" to see if that fixed things, and the error then appeared at the ":" character at the end of the line, but the message was the same.

I've looked elsewhere on this site and read something about this being evidence of a problem BEFORE the highlighted text, but nothing more specific than that.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Missing parenthesis are an easy mistake to make. I do it all the time. When you think your ready, I suggest getting a dedicated python IDE. they warn about this kind of stuff. And loads of other pre-runtime errors. A popular one is [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have a syntax error with the following line above it:

```
spent_points = int(input("How many points will you spend?: ")
```

change this to

```
spent_points = int(input("How many points will you spend?: "))
```

Note that this happens every time you have the pattern int(input(...).  So add that extra parenthesis to all of the cases and you should be good to go.

Also, I should note that once you get past that you will run into an IndentionError with your if chosen_stat == "2": statements.  Looks like you have a space hidden before the "if" statements.  Backspace one time before each one to get rid of the error.

Comment: Thank you very much! So simple. Rookie mistake on my part.

Comment: OH yeah, sorry. I'm new to this site.